# How to construct a Python pandas series of objects whose attributes fall within a range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas.Series, S, of objects where each object, t, has several attributes, one of which is its length, t.len. I want to create another series SL comprising of those objects in S that have a length between the 60th and the 90th percentile of the objects in S. What is the most efficient way to code this?

Suppose, `S = [t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9]` is a series of 10 objects. A list of their corresponding lengths is `[15, 4, 10, 20, 3, 20, 13, 8, 14, 1]`. The 60th percentile length is 13.4, and the 90th percentile length is 20. Then `SL = [t0, t3, t5, t8]`

Here is the code based on series.between, but it produces an error, namely:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Object:
    def __init__(self, tid, length):
        self.tid = tid        
        self.len = length

objectseries = pd.Series([Object(0, 15), Object(1, 4), Object(2, 10), Object(3, 20), Object(4, 3), Object(5, 20), Object(6, 13), Object(7, 8), Object(8, 14), Object(9, 1)])
lenseries = pd.Series(x.len for x in objectseries)
ll = np.percentile(lenseries, 60)
uu = np.percentile(lenseries, 90)
sl = lenseries.between(ll,uu)
print (sl)
objectlist = objectseries.tolist()
print (objectlist[sl])
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including sample input, sample output, and code for what you've tried so far

Comment: `s[slen.between(13.4,20)]`?

Comment: The slen.between actually gives an error. I have added my code above. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `quantile` to get the percentile values and use `between`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'object':[f't{i}' for i in range(10)],
              'values':[15, 4, 10, 20, 3, 20, 13, 8, 14, 1]})

q60,q90 = df['values'].quantile([0.6, 0.9])

df.loc[df['values'].between(q60,q90), 'object']
```

Output:

```
0    t0
3    t3
5    t5
8    t8
Name: object, dtype: object
```